# TextInputLayout with an exposed dropdown menu does not return to its original form (hint center vertical) if no item is selected

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-textinputlayout

if you open the drop-down list and without selecting any item close the drop-down list, the hint will remain in the top position. `TextInputLayout` will return to its original state (the hint is centered vertically) only after the focus moves to another element.
XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:hint="@string/register_children_child_name_hint"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/black_5_new"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/gray_new">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textAppearance="@style/NormalText"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

how can I make it return to its original state if the drop-down list is closed and no items are selected?
I tried `clearFocus()` but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why when opening the drop-down list, `TextInputLayout` immediately went into an active state and did not return to its original state when drop-down list closed. I call `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` in my code. When I removed this line, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = ((AutoCompleteTextView)textinputlayout.getEditText());
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnDismissListener(new AutoCompleteTextView.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            autoCompleteTextView.clearFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but writing this code is not necessary, everything would work correctly if I hadn’t specified focusableInTouchMode(true) in the code.